# how to use background image in twitter boostrap navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I have experienced to customize the twitter bootstrap navbar color successfully..
Now I want to use an image as the navbar background, so I could play more with the navbar..

But when I put the css "background: url(/img/navbar-bg.png) repeat-x;" in the navbar-inner..
it doesnt work, anyone know why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you do it like this it should work.

```
.navbar-inner{
  background-image: url('navbar-bg.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Demo: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/LjWUs/90/show/)

Comment: Doesn't work in IE9, bootstraps css for gradients takes precedence over the background image.

Comment: For me it works fine in IE9. I edit the sample above a bit so the styles are more specified. You have to include the css below the bootstrap css include. If that doesn't work use the !important tag. -> http://jsfiddle.net/LjWUs/47/show/